# Trying to make a bootable usb that I can use for Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb

So I am trying to make a bootable usb drive so I can test out Ubuntu. I have burned it to the usb, disabled fast boot etc. and everything I can find I'm supposed to do, but when I go in the BIOS Menu and choose the usb, it says it fails? I have Windows 8.1.

Comment: So, the BIOS says that the USB fails? ...or the USB says that it fails? Also, you need to detail the way of Writing the image to the USB.

Comment: It tells me that the deleted boot device fails? I used unetbootin, did I not download the right file off the Ubuntu site?

Comment: Did your machine come with Win 8 preinstalled (i.e. an UEFI machine)?  Which file did you download?  Did you hashcheck it?  Did you ever run the "check media" option on the install media?

Comment: Ok. So I have downloaded and installed it, I don't think my Windows 8.1 deleted but it isn't showing up on the boot menu. I am trying to edit the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file, but it won't let me due to root permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using UNetBootin (https://unetbootin.github.io/) on Windows 8. To be sure, I usually ran this as Administrator and usually formatted the USB stick before hand even though the software will do this.

Comment: Yeah this is the best that has given me reliable live USBs even on Ubuntu